# iOS 13/iPhone 7: Abnormally high data usage by system services and apps

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, data

I have been observing excessively high data usage each month that appears to be way more then I am actually using.

I have always had background data turned off and tried to limit the amount of content that I was streaming or using within apps once I noticed the extreme amounts of data being consumed. So It just doesn’t match up when I see how much data the network says I used per month and what I was actually using.

Also, the breakdown of data usage per app doesn’t ever appear accurate either, because there are some apps that I have never had data turned on for, and those apps are showing usage as well. It almost looks like the amount of data that the network is delivering is just being divided up and passed off as being used by apps that aren’t in fact using the data.

It sounds paranoid but it really does seem like the OS is using a shit ton of data each month and trying to pass it off by adding it to the usage of apps that I use and even some that I never even open and have all data shut off to. It’s weird.

I am up to 53GB already this month and the most useage that I do per day is stream maybe a half hour of video and use Surfline app to check surf and read news. Plus miscellaneous web browsing. But 50GB of data within a month seems like it is way more than what my average daily use is.

Maybe I am wrong and it really does take that much but because of the fact that I can’t get it to decrease even when I shut all data off to all apps and only turn on when using, then I still get huge usage amounts and even showing up under some apps that I never even used or turned data on for.  It just doesn’t seem right.

What could be causing this? Attached are the pictures of the cellular usage screen from the Settings app:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Also, there are a whole bunch of system services that use data too and I have no idea what they do. It seems like the list of system services also got really long over last couple updates. I was just wondering if everyone running iOS 13 has this many services under system services list, or if this is an abnormal amount of services for iOS to be running and using data.

Just wondering if all of this is normal. Also post are the pics below of the system services list with the usages.

Just wondering if any of it seems odd to anyone else and if the system services are all normal for iOS 13.

[image] [image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you scroll all the way down on the Mobile Data screen under the Settings app and check Last Reset date for the statistics? The reported usage is aggregate since the data/time of last reset. So there's a possibility that you may have not reset it ever or in a long while. Nothing appears to be out of the ordinary in the list of System Services.

Comment: It was reset feb 7 2020.   So those totals you see are since then. But I normally use my network to give me monthly data totals. I just use this list of applications to get an idea of what apps are using the data and how quickly, not nessasarily to calculate the monthly totals.

Comment: I just wanted to see how my phone was using that much data when my network was saying that and I didn’t think I used anywhere close to that much.   And even when I cut down massively on usage or turned certain apps data off I still had massive data usage those months and even showing up under certain apps that I had data shut off too and didn’t use.  I can’t understand where the data goes each month when I have Limited individual app usage it’s like something else sucks up the data. But can’t tell what.  Like iOS whole system??

Comment: I'm curious if you ever found a solution. I seem to be having a similar issue, sudden, dramatic increase in data usage